# Subscripting itertools.repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Given that `range` objects were made subscriptable, why aren't `itertools.repeat` objects subscriptable?

```
In [10]: range(3, 10)[3]
Out[10]: 6

In [11]: import itertools as it

In [12]: it.repeat(5)[3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1ef74480e0a7> in <module>()
----> 1 it.repeat(5)[3]

TypeError: 'itertools.repeat' object is not subscriptable
```

**Note that range objects and itertools.repeat objects are part of Python 3.**

I would prefer:

```
class repeat_(itertools.repeat):
    def __init__(self, object_, times=None):
        super().__init__(object_, times)

        self.object_ = object_
        self.times = times

    def __reversed__(self):
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.object_

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key == self.object_

    def __len__(self):
        if self.times is None:
            raise ValueError
        return self.times
```

Comment: Yeah, `list(range(50000000)[:5])` produces the same thing as `islice(range(50000000), 5)`, so why can't `list(repeat(4)[:5])` produce the same as `list(islice(repeat(4), 5))`?  It seems like a simpler way to say exactly the same thing.

Comment: @endolith: Good answers here: http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/Why-are-generators-in-python-not-subscriptable

Comment: @endolith: Thanks, but I disagree that itertools.repeat had to be an iterator.  It could have been a plain old iterable.  As it is, I had to subclass `itertools.repeat`.

Answer (score 4):

`repeat` just yields the same object over and over again.  I'm not really sure what subscripting it would actually do for you ... You would be just as well to call `next(repeat_object)`.  Perhaps you are thinking about `cycle` (as I did when I originally read your question)?

Part the the wonder of `itertools` is that it attempts to operate as lazily as it possibly can.  In light of this, what do you expect to happen if you pass a generator expression to `itertools.cycle`?  `cycle` has **NO WAY** to know the length of the object you passed in short of casting the whole thing to a tuple and inquiring.  Doing that would probably break the API in a bunch of other places (now you consume your iterable when you subscript your repeat object) or it would take a whole lot more intermediate storage via an unnecessary `itertools.tee` -- which is what `itertools` tries to avoid.  As it is currently implemented, `cycle` on a huge generator expression that you can't hope to hold in memory works (as long as you don't actually iterate over all the elements), but that wouldn't be the case if you tried to subscript it at a large index.

Finally, as the name implies, `itertools` is a library for creating `iterable` objects.  As such, there is no reason to expect that the objects are subscriptable.  (It's not called `subscripttools` after all :).

As a side note, you might be able to do what you want with `itertools.islice`.

Comment: `itertools.repeat()` just repeats the object over and over again. Are you thinking of `.cycle()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yes, I was thinking of `cycle` ... I suppose I'll have to edit now.

Comment: I'm using repeat objects polymorphically (in a sequence of sequence objects.) I don't know a priori that the sequence I've got is a repeat object. I try subscripting all of my sequence objects, but it unfortunately fails for repeat objects

Comment: You can try/except for that special case, or you can wrap your repeat's in a class which is subscriptable (which just uses `next` as proposed above), or you could use `islice` for all of them, although this is likely to be inefficient.

Comment: Thank you, I will probably just use `islice` since I am not concerned about efficiency.  If people agree with http://bugs.python.org/issue16540, then I would be happy to write the patch.

Comment: "`repeat` on a huge generator expression"... I think you meant `cycle`. Repeating a generator just returns the generator object. Subscripting could be added to `count`, `cycle`, and `repeat`. For example the [`saved` list](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l907) in `cycle` could be advanced up to the requested index (or `StopIteration`), but it would require adding more state, a bit more logic, and using `PyList_GET_ITEM`.

Comment: @eryksun -- Thanks for that -- I did mean `cycle` there.  Yes, it *could* be done, but you'd need to save more state and consume more of the iterable the was passed in (if the iterable is consumable).  The point is that `itertools` is a library for creating lazy iterables.  I think that adding subscription makes it a little less lazy and you don't really gain that much (considering you could use `islice` to do the same thing much more explicitly).

Comment: But why would you ever want an iterable that is not subscriptable?  Why shouldn't `repeat(4)[:5]` produce the same thing as `islice(repeat(4), 5)`?

Comment: @endolith -- because you can't sanely islice it more than once.  e.g. `a = iter(range(30)); b = a[:5]; c = a[:3]` would give very different results than slicing a list in this situation which would probably make the code less clear.

Comment: @mgilson: You can sanely slice `repeat` more than once, but yes, for general iterators I see that it would result in insanity.

Comment: @endolith -- Right.  I wasn't talking about `repeat(4)` specifically.  That iterable is pretty regular ;-).  I was talking about the arbitrary iterable case.

Comment: I don't find this argument very convincing.  Wouldn't it be easy for `cycle` to be subscriptable only if the underlying iterable is subscriptable as well?

Comment: Not really.  What does it mean to subscript a `cycle` after you've already taken a few elements out of it for example?  Also, if you make a `cycle` and pass it to something else, should it expect to be able to subscript it or not?  Obviously the safe thing is to assume you can't, but then you lose the benefits of being able to subscript it :-) and if you're doing that someplace local, you can easily do `sequence[index % len(sequence)]` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[itertool.repeat()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) method returns an iterator, not a list, as is the case with `range` function. So, you can't subscript on it.

Here's what documentation says: -

> Make an iterator that returns object over and over again. Runs
>   indefinitely unless the times argument is specified.

From [documentation of range](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html): -

> If you do need to iterate over a sequence of numbers, the built-in
>   function range() comes in handy. It generates lists containing
>   arithmetic progressions

---

In *Python 3*, difference is that, `range()` creates a `Generator` object. Which `xrange` function in *Python 2* did.

Comment: In Python 3, range does not return a list, and it is nevertheless subscriptable.

Comment: @NeilG.. But in Python 2.x, since it returns a list, we can of course subscript on a list. right? So, why you said, it does not return list in Python 3, so we can subscript?

Comment: yes, in Python 3, it returns a "range object", which is not a list, but nevertheless supports subscripting.

Comment: @NeilG: It is a specialized object, not a generic iterator. Each iterator would have to implement that explicitly, it is not a standard feature of iterators.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Don't you think that it should implement subscripting?

Comment: @NeilG: File a feature request with the Python project then. For *most* iterators subscription does not make sense. For a range, it is trivial to implement, for many others it is not.

Comment: @RohitJain: Really, a python 1.4 link? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree with that, but I was wondering if there was a good reason not to have it subscriptable.  Where do you file feature requests?

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. Ah! I got that link at the top. Will add the latest one.

Comment: @NeilG: Note that it doesn't make sense *at all* for `.repeat()` to be subscriptable. It repeats the same element *over* and *over* again. So `repeat(10)[1]` is the same thing as `repeat(10)[101]`. So you may as well use `repeat(10).next()` instead.

Comment: @RohitJain: In python 3, `range()` is a type, not a function. So the returned value is a [special sequence type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm using repeat objects polymorphically (in a sequence of sequence objects.)  I don't know a priori that the sequence I've got is a repeat object.  I try subscripting all of my sequence objects, but it unfortunately fails for repeat objects.

Comment: @NeilG: You should test with the sequence abstract base class then, perhaps, to see if something is indeed usable as a sequence. `range()` passes that test, iterators don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're right, but it didn't need to be an iterator.  It could have been a plain old iterable with subscripting support like range.